# Waiting for message to be sent, then storing the last message as a variable. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to write some code that sends a message, then waits for a response, then stores that response as a variable.

the code that I have so far looks like this

```
import discord
global sMessage
sMessage = message.content.replace('`', '')
client.wait_for(sMessage)
channel = client.get_channel("(the id of my channel)")
msgtest = channel.history(limit = 1)
await message.channel.send(msgtest)
```

this code, unfortunately, doesn't work. if anyone knows how I would go about getting this code to work, I'd appreciate it.
( Discord.py )

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong use. You can see [the official reference.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the message like any other variable:

```py
message = await client.wait_for('message')
```

You can add a check function to make sure the message is sent by the user that used the command

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author

message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```